# Creating ArcMap toolbar button from model tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, toolbar

Using Arc 10.3.1 ModelBuilder, I've just successfully created my first tool, which is stored in a toolbox within "My Toolboxes".  I run the tool by opening the Arc Toolbox button, dropping down to the tool and double-clicking it.

Now I'd like to make a toolbar button from my tool.  I envision running the tool by simply clicking the new button rather than scrolling down through the Arc Toolbox dropdown.  I've read through the book "Getting to Know ArcGIS Modelbuilder", plus a web search, plus the ESRI help documents.  Nothing I've seen helps...

In summary, how do I convert a tool to a toolbar button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to Customize> Customize Mode on the Menu bar, in ArcMap.  From there, click the commands tab, and select "Geoprocessing Tools" in the category list.  Then browse to your toolbox containing the model and select it.  This brings in the model to the commands.  Now you can place it in a toolbar.

Comment: Excellent!  In order to place my new tool in a toolbar, I simply dragged its  icon from the Commands tab to the toolbar.  Prior to that I made my own toolbar  to put the tool in with Customize > Toolbars > New... which immediately placed it with all the other toolbars.